# How to Embed Gumlet videos in HTML?

Tags: video, html5-video, streaming, embedding

I am new to Videos and started using [gumlet.com](https://www.gumlet.com), but I am unsure how to embed it in the HTML & emails.

I used `<iframe src="https://www.gumlet.com/watch/64a651e54dc6e9c15e3aa689">` but it didn't work.

[image: Want to see someting like this]

I want to add the video to the email with a link to the full video.

What are the ways to achieve both of the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *" I am unsure how to embed it in the HTML"*

To embed just **replace** any **gumlet.com/watch/** in your links with  **play.gumlet.io/embed/**

For example:

```
https://www.gumlet.com/watch/64a651e54dc6e9c15e3aa689
```

Becomes the correct version below for embedding usage:

```
https://play.gumlet.io/embed/64a651e54dc6e9c15e3aa689
```

Comment: @vc-one, do you know how to Embed it in the email draft like Gmail?

Comment: Gmail (and many others) don't allow iframes inside emails. It is for security purposes. All you can do is add a nice picture (video thumbnail) with some text underneath for a link to watch on another page.